# How to use single column from composite key in jpaql or hql query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-key

Provider is hibernate 3.6.

I have a composite key declared via @IdClass, consisting of 4 columns.  Everything works fine when it comes to storing and retrieving entity instances via a complete primary key.  However, if I wish to query for all entities that have a particular value in just a single column, hibernate throws exceptions.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyBeanId.class)
public class MyBean {
    @Id
    private Integer partId1;
    @Id
    private Integer partId2;
    @Id
    private Integer partId3;
    @Id
    private String partId4;
    private Integer otherProperty1;
    private Double otherProperty2;
    private Double otherProperty3;
    private String otherProperty4;

        /* removed getters and setters */
}
```

query code in another class:

```
public List<MyBean> findByPartId1(Integer partId1) {
    return em.createQuery("select b from MyBean b where b.partId1 = :partId1", MyBean.class).setParameter("partId1", partId1).getResultList();
}
```

Another query which is failing, with an error message about not knowing the type of a parameter is as follows:

```
public List<Integer> getAllPartId1s() {
    return em.createQuery("select distinct b.partId1 from MyBean b", Integer.class).getResultList();
}
```

The exception I'm getting from the first query is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: partId1 of: some.company.entity.MyBean [select t from some.company.entity.MyBean b where b.partId1 = :partId1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1465)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1330)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3944)
```

Surely, there is some way to access the individual columns of a composite key in a query without resorting to an @Embeddable id object?  Otherwise, why even have the @IdClass mechanism, since it is all but useless. I've tried numerous variants, such as "where b.id.partId1 = :partId1" but they all fail.

And yes, I have a MyBeanId class with the same properties and a valid hashCode and equals, but there is only so much code I want to sanitize in order to post a question.

Comment: In you query `select b from MyBean b where t.partId1 = :partId1` why you have mentioned `t.partId1`, shouldn't it be `b.partId1` or it is just a typo.

Comment: Does any query on MyBean work?  ie "select m from MyBean m"?  How about any other attribute on MyBean or is it only one of the IDs that gives you trouble?

Comment: Nayan, yes, it's a typo.  I changed all of the names and queries in order to sanitize code and I missed that one.  The query is correct in my actual code.  Chris, queries that don't reference properties that are part of the composite id work fine.  "Select m from MyBean m" works fine, as does "select m from MyBean m where m.otherProerty1 = :someValue"

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it is way too late to answer your query now (after 3 years). Also, the way I am using uses @EmbeddedId and not @IdClass But just thought it may help others who might land up here looking for an answer to a similar problem.

You can put all the fields consisting your composite key in a different class as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyBeanId {
private Integer partId1;

private Integer partId2;

private Integer partId3;

private String partId4;
}
```

Use that class in your entity:

```
public class MyBean {
 @EmbeddedId
 private MyBeanId id;
 // other attrbute goes here
}
```

and then write the query as:

```
public List<Integer> getAllPartId1s() {
  return em.createQuery("select distinct b.id.partId1 from MyBean b"....
}
```